# Getting 403 : Forbidden when using POST HttpMethod

Tags: salesforce-id, netsuite

I have trying to integration between NetSuite and SFDC using OAuth Token. I have successfully called GET API Request from APEX Class but whenever I am trying to call a POST Method it would always give me an error with `403 : Forbidden error`.
(In extra it says `INVALID_USER_LOGIN`, But though it is working in GET Request with OAuth Token).

Could someone help me to figure it out?